# What is (dimension-theory)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

We have evidently a [dimension-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-theory) tag. It does not have currently a tag wiki. My understanding of dimension theory is that it refers to either

- The branch of topology that studies dimensional invariants of topological spaces, and treats stuff like Lebesgue covering dimensions and inductive dimensions.
- The study of dimension of a commutative ring.

The original creator of the tag seems to have used it to mean the latter, and some posts currently using the tag uses the former.

**But** it seems that a lot of users are using the tag for completely different things: the dimension of a vector space in linear algebra, Hausdorff dimension of sets in (geometric) measure theory, counting degrees of freedom in ... well, something.

I would like to clean up the tag a bit. But before we do that, we should first agree on what the scope of [dimension-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-theory) is, and what we should put into a tag-wiki.

Comment: I've edited the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/dimension-theory/info) to include the information about dimension theory from general topology. Perhaps someone, who is more familiar with it, might add something about dimension of ring. Of course, if we see from this discussion that some other meanings should be included, too; we can change the tag-wiki and tag-excerpt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is reasonable to use [dimension-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-theory) for dimension in general topology (which might include Hausdorff dimension) and commutative algebra.

Definitely not for questions from linear algebra.